# How to Prevent Both beginDialogAction and triggerAction from Executing in Microsoft Bot Builder SDK

Tags: node.js, botframework

Note: I am using Microsoft Bot Builder's SDK in Node.js.

### The Desired Task

I am attempting to use beginDialogAction to initiate another sub-dialog so that by the end of the sub-dialog dialog, the stack would go right back to the dialog they left off. At the same time, however, I want to give the user the *option* of activating this same sub-dialog as a triggerAction in any other conversation.

### The Problem

Implementing as follows puts TWO COPIES of the sub-dialog in the stack, by both the triggerAction and beginDialogAction. This is unwanted behavior because once one of those dialogs complete, a duplicate of that dialog runs again.

Here is the code:

```
// user dialog
bot.dialog('/', [
    function (session, args, next) {
       session.send('Starting root dialog');
    },
    function (session) {
        session.send('Ending root dialog.');
]).beginDialogAction('addUser', 'UserAdd', {
    matches: /^user add$/i
});

// branch dialog
bot.dialog('UserAdd', [
    function (session, args, next) {
        session.send('Adding user.');
}
]).triggerAction({
    matches: /^user add$/i
})
```

### The Question

What is the correct way to enable both a beginDialogAction and triggerAction of a dialog, but only run that dialog ONCE if it is triggered by a beginDialogAction, so that the root dialog can continue where it left off? If this is not traditional way of thinking to use this framework, I welcome other perspectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is unwanted behavior because once one of those dialogs complete, a duplicate of that dialog runs again.

I couldn't reproduce this issue. The problem in your code is that you didn't end the `UserAdd` dialog after it is triggered whether it is called by `beginDialogAction` or `triggerAction`, this makes the dialog stack always stays inside of this `UserAdd` dialog and never end.

Based on your description, I don't think there would be any conflicts between `beginDialogAction` and `triggerAction`, tried to modify your code as below and it works fine on my side:

```
bot.dialog('/', [
    function (session, args, next) {
       session.send('Starting root dialog');
       builder.Prompts.text(session, "How many people are in your party?");
    },
    function (session, results) {
       builder.Prompts.text(session, "Who will be there?");
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.send('Ending root dialog.');
        session.endDialog();
    }
])
.beginDialogAction('addUser', 'UserAdd', {
    matches: /^user add$/i
})

//  // branch dialog
bot.dialog('UserAdd', [
    function (session, args, next) {
        session.send('Adding user.');
        session.endDialog();
}
]).triggerAction({
    matches: /^user add$/i
});
```

If there's any further concern or more problem, please feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful and helpful reply. Your post led me to the conclusion that there was some other problem going on. Surely enough, I found that the problem did not have to do so much with the beginDialogAction and triggerAction both getting run, but rather, that I needed to call `session.endConversation()` at the end of the subdialog in order to leave the dialog that was "hung" after calling the subdialog.